# Additional organization fields

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I propose adding **Location**, **Description**, and **Website** fields for the organization to each entry in the experience segment of a Careers profile.

Sometimes the name of an organization is not enough to uniquely identify it. Even if it is, a name is usually not enough to show tell what the company does or even what industry it is in. Also, many companies have employees in multiple locations, so the location field would be useful for specifying which branch/campus/region the candidate worked at.

Comment: What would be the benefit for future employers that they know in which campus you work?

Comment: For example, if the you worked for a US-based company, but worked in Brazil, I think that is meaningful information about your experience. As a counterexample, I don't think it matters if you worked at Building 1 or Building 2 when both are in the same city.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the developer that worked on the new profile UI. For all this information, I would put it in what is currently the "Responsibilities" section of the form.

[image: Responsibilities section]

Granted, this is not labelled correctly, and I think we should change it to "Description". We've seen this textarea commonly used in this way anyways and I think it's time we changed it. I'll see what we can do about that soon.

Comment: I use the responsibilities text area that way, and it more-or-less works. I also type the city alongside the company name, e.g. "Stack Exchange Inc. (New York, NY)". However, having fields specifically for this purpose would remind candidates to enter this information and give profiles a more consistent look for prospective employers.